# Does vaadin has analog to html thead

Tags: html-table, header, grid, vaadin

In my Vaadin application I need to present several tables. They are similar in structure but have different headers. In plain old HTML I would specify those headers in the thead section of table.
I did look for something similar in Vaadin Grid, but didn't find anything similar.
I certainly can separate tables with Label, but wonder if I did miss something and this feature does exist.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're looking to do, but the Vaadin Grid component does have a `<thead>` element (see screenshot) – but the API hides it behind its own abstractions. Instead of creating it directly, you specify a header for each column, which will then generate `<th>` elements inside the Grid's `<thead>`, e.g.

```
grid.addColumn(Person::getFirstName).setHeader("First name");
```

[image]

Comment: No, I wasn't looking for column headers. As I said I have several tables with identical structures but different headers (and certainly data).  I.e. 1st table has a header "FY2022- Q1", 2nd table - "FY2022-Q2" and so on.

Comment: Ok then could you describe what it is you are trying to do? Because your question is about whether or not Vaadin has something similar to the thead element in html tables, which I just answered. Perhaps you're thinking of a title above the table itself? (But that would not be done with thead in plain html either)

Comment: An image would help immensely.